# Can you pass parameters to controllers through routes.rb without them appearing in the URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Suppose I want www.example.com/profile to redirect a user to his or her profile page. So what I want to do is match "/profile" to "users#show" but also let the controller know who the current user is. Is there any way I can set params[:id] or params[:user_id] to session[:user_id] in the routes file? I know this might not be the best way to accomplish what I want to accomplish. I just want to know if it's possible, and how to do it if it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Route '/profile' to 'users#show', then set the params value to the session value if it is not already set. You can't set this in your routes file, but you can do it in the controller.

Routes:

```
match '/profile' => 'users#show
```

Controller:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController

  def show
    params[:id] ||= session[:user_id]

    @user = User.find(params[:id)
  end

end
```

You'll want to do some extra checking in your controller to make sure your user actually is who they say they are in the session, I assume you are using some sort of authentication library.

Comment: in your case, route should look like: `match '/profile/(:id)' => 'users#show
`

Comment: I was assuming there would also be a `resource :user` route, should have said that.

Comment: even in this case: I think `id` is a necessary param. That's why it should be rewritten

Answer (score 0):

If you want to accomplish this, you shouldn't let it appear in your routes at all.

It should remain:

```
match "/profile" to "users#profile"
```

Because you have the information in session, you only have to fetch it in your controller.

```
User.find(session[:user_id])
```

The best is to put a `before_filter` checking whether or not the user is logged so that you won't face an error because the session is nil.